# Derived Column Error

Tags: sql, ssis

I have a column in table which needs to be replaced with certain  part of the word to an another one I used Derived column but There is no change at all

Ex:

Input:

```
S.no        Name             Department
1           Mike             San Diego Soceity Office
2           Stat             New York Soceity Office
```

Output should be like

```
S.no        Name             Department
1           Mike             San Diego S.O
2           Stat             New York S.O
```

In derived column i used the following code

```
Replace(Department,"Soceity Office", "S.O")
```

Confidentiality

Comment: Could you add a print screen of the SSIS process?

Comment: I had to change the data For confidentiality purpose

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The other thing to be aware beyond misspellings as @sqlgrl pointed out (and welcome to the [ssis] tag) is that string operations are going to be case sensitive.

```
REPLACE(Department,"Soceity Office","S.O.")
```

You can see below, I took your sample data and ran it through two different replace statements. One accounts for the proper spelling of Society, the other uses your spelling (which is probably why you're standardizing to S.O.)

[image]

Originally, I had used "Soceity office" and was observing no change and again, that is due to a casing issue.

Comment: In your attached screenshots, you have a space surrounding your replace string. Your source data has no trailing space.

Comment: can we convert like Replace(department,"ram's","ram")

Answer (score 2):

Maybe try checking your spelling?  Is it possible that you are trying to replace Society Office not Soceity Office in the Department field?  Otherwise the code looks good to me.

```
Replace(Department,"Society Office", "S.O")
```

Comment: I just cant figure it out and I am confused I kept the same thing but it doesn't work :(